# How to update the update first element of array of property values from a relationship?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am having a relationship like below which has 2 value for a relationship property.
DURATION["100","100"]  ..My intention is to update first value to have different type of values..

I want to update a first value of the array..
Below is what I am trying to do by using cypher query..

```
MATCH (a:emp),(b:emp) WHERE a.PHONE_NUMBER='200' AND b.PHONE_NUMBER='100' CREATE (a)-[r:TRAVEL]->(b) SET r.DURATION[0] = ['233']
```

I am getting error while trying access the first field from array.. ...
It should be something like this  ....
DURATION["200","100"]

Any specific syntax for this type of update ??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
CREATE (a)-[r:TRAVEL]->(b) SET r.DURATION[0] = ['233']
```

You can use:

```
MERGE (a)-[r:TRAVEL]->(b)
ON MATCH SET r.DURATION = "233" + r.DURATION[1..]
```

Comment: No..After executing ...there is no property available ...MATCH (caller:CUSTOMER),(receiver:CUSTOMER) WHERE caller.PHONE_NUMBER='200' AND receiver.PHONE_NUMBER='100' CREATE (caller)-[r:CALLED]->(receiver) SET r.DURATION = "233"+r.DURATION[1..]

Comment: ah, you need to `MERGE` the relationship (inestead of MATCH) and do the `SET` in a `ON MATCH` clause.